# aspx adds extra html sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, aspx

Is there a way to stop the .aspx page on SharePoint 2010 to keep adding the html tags?

```
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:ContentType msdt:dt="string">Page</mso:ContentType>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string">, </mso:PublishingContactPicture>   </mso:CustomDocumentProperties></xml><![endif]-->
<meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document">
</head>
```

SharePoint 2007 did not use to do this. Is there a way to remove this, or prevent it from being populated?

Comment: but first you can change the list setting Versioning settings -> Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited? -> no
great diana thanx a lot i stuk in this issue before 2 days

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to finally figure it out. I don't remember what blog it was, but what they did is they exported the file to their desktop, then they opened it in notepad and removed the extra code sharepoint was adding. Once you have your file clean, you can re-import it back.